# Google's blue arrow doesn't show up until I TAB

Tags: google-search

I didn't really know what to name this question, and I have no idea what's causing this either.

Usually when you do a google search a little arrow shows up to the left of the first result, so all you need is to press *Enter* and you go straight to the first result. Lately though, that hasn't been working for me. After I do the google search, the arrow only shows up if I press *TAB* first and that usually messes up everything (since *TAB* means "select next link" in most browsers).

EDIT: OK, it seems this is a [feature](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=191139). The problem is: this feature doesn't work at all in Firefox. When I hit tab, the blue arrow does show up but Firefox also selects the first link he finds on the page (usually the "+1" button). This way, if I hit Enter, instead of entering the page, I just mark the entry as +1.

So the instructions provided in [Google's help page](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=191139) ("TAB, then ENTER") don't really work.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Hitting down-right also works. Not really easier though.

Comment: @Pubby8: Nope, that doesn't work either. For some reason the blue arrow doesn't show up at ALL until I hit TAB.

Comment: Down-right doesn't move the cursor, but it does bring up a "I'm feeling lucky" option. At least for me.

Comment: @Pubby8 I see what you mean now. That's a good suggestion. Unfortunately I'm usually searching directly from the urlbar. You gave me an idea though, I'll just change the urlbar to use the "feeling lucky" option. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google changed the behaviour recently, so this isn't an issue with your setup.

It says you need to hit tab to get the blue arrow [here](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=191139).

Comment: In that case, Is there anyway to prevent tab from focusing some link? Usually, when I hit tab, the blue arrow does show up but Firefox also selects the first link he finds on the page (usually the "+1" button). This way, if I hit Enter, instead of entering the page, I just mark the entry as +1.

Comment: Oh yeah, it like firefox and Google are conflicting witht the behaviour - Google takes the first tab to activate the keyboard controls which moves focus to the first url, but ff then reacts to the tab and moves the focus to the second url - which can be the +1 or even the second entry in the list.  Pressing up/down puts it back in the right place, but I don't think there is a way you can fix this.  Beyond using Chrome, which doesn't do this.